How to execute the certain time series segment deletion statement in Apache IoTDB?
I am trying to execute delete from root.ln.wf02.* where time >=100 and time <= 120 command in Apache IoTDB, and I cannot delete the field value in a certain time series segment. Did I use this deletion wrong, or this deletion is to only delete the whole time series sequence (similar to deleting the entire column in the database)?

In Apache IoTDB, including .* in query statement only matches one level down the MTree data structure, but including .** means to match any level. Therefore, if you want to only delete one specific field value in IoTDB, then you need to switch the .* you use to .** to do that.
